# Values passed on TextViews not updated on UI of Android Application

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

I am coding an application related with medical tests. In the test fragments i want to clear the patient data before (or during user-switch phase) in order to be entered and submitted.
In the related fragments i have this code (using data binding) :

```
fun initPatientData() {
    checkBinding.ageEdTxt.setText("")
    checkBinding.ageEdTxt.invalidate()
    setRaceData("White")
    setSexData("MALE")
    checkBinding.sbbEdTxt.setText("")
    checkBinding.tchEdTxt.setText("")
    checkBinding.hchEdTxt.setText("")
    checkBinding.SmokeRGr.clearCheck()
    checkBinding.TreatRadioGroup.clearCheck()
}
```

Although i am initializing the values, i do not see them updated on the UI when i run the app. What might be the issue for this?

Kind Regards,
Lampros

Comment: show how and where you are creating `checkBinding`

Comment: In Fragment : 

    private lateinit var checkBinding: FragmentCheckBinding

        onCreateView :    
     
checkBinding = FragmentCheckBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

On fragment layout .xml : 

    <data>
        <variable
            name="checkPatientViewModel"
            type="com.example.cvdriskestimator.viewModels.CheckPatientViewModel"
        />
    </data>

Comment: nothing suspicious in currently posted code, are you 100% shure that `initPatientData` get called at all? post some more lines, logic at first, and in question edited, no comment